# How to overwrite to remote branch in git even though there is conflicts?

Tags: git, github

I know that There is conflicts between my changes and remote branch changes.But how do i overwrite remote branch changes.I tried git push --force.But it says ! [remote rejected] (non-fast-forward).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you shouldn't change something on the target site. When you create conflicts on that site it can broke your complete site if you have the merge commits in your code.

On the Target site you can pull your changes with `--force` or you make a hard reset to the last state your need then you can pullt and don't get some new changes. Before your have to push with force.

Otherwise add and commit the changes on the target site then push them and resolve the conflicts local by pulling the changes.

Comment: But we have option like "override and commit" in SVN .When i know that there is conflict and i want to overwrite that on remote i can use this.When i try to do --force it should not check for conflicts.Still im getting the error.And when i used --force i know what im doing.If i pull from remote,my changes are lost.